# Bucket sort using fully qualified file name question - really a parse question

Tags: c#, text-parsing

I can do this but my solution seems a bit of a hack so thought I would ask SO to get a more elegant solution. I need to take a list of fully qualified file names and sort/copy them into a few buckets based on a substring in the path name.

I have three buckets, maybe more and can change. Say I have three buckets these files are copied to, like "foo", "foo\bar" and "foo\baz". So the file C:\mumble\foo\bar\thing.extension goes into the foo\bar bucket, and C:\fumble\foo\baz\this\is\another\directory\bling.extension goes to the \foo\baz bucket, and D:\stumble\foo\something.extension goes into the foo bucket. I need to redirect the files so I've been using IndexOf (so I can create the direction of the copy), but that does not really work very well because \foo and foo\bar are similar and need different buckets. Then I thought I could use file.Contains, but \foo and \foo\baz go into different buckets so need a priority, foo\bar to one but \foo to another.

Any ideas how to do this with relative simplicity? My code is embarrassing.

Thanks Doug

Comment: Wouldn't regular expressions help your case? You can use the greedy quantifiers to obtain the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to this.

```
    private static readonly Regex _foo = new Regex(@"\\foo\\(?! (bar|baz)\\)",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    private static readonly Regex _foobar = new Regex(@"\\foo\\bar\\",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    private static readonly Regex _foobaz = new Regex(@"\\foo\\baz\\",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

...

```
        foreach (var filename in files)
        {
            if (_foo.IsMatch(filename))
            {
                // bucket foo
            }
            else if (_foobar.IsMatch(filename))
            {
                // bucket foobar
            }
            else if (_foobaz.IsMatch(filename))
            {
                // bucket foobaz
            }
        }
```

...

Alternatively, take out the negative lookahead in _foo and just make it the last condition of the if statement.

Comment: Because this sort can be changed at any time, I decided to use regex as you suggest but insert the conditions into a config file rather than hard code. Thanks, I thought of regex but had not considered reading it from a file.